# Google Checkout is timing out

Tags: django, timeout, google-checkout, satchmo

I working on a Satchmo site that uses Google Checkout. I've resolved the SSL issues I was having, but the Google integration console is still giving me the following error:

"We encountered an error trying to access your server at https://bernunzio.dxdt.org/checkout/google/notification/ -- the error we got is java.io.IOException: Error 'TIMEOUT' connecting to url 'https://bernunzio.dxdt.org/checkout/google/notification/'."

I tried getting the POST data from the integration console and manually submitting it to my site via curl and it works fine, so the problem must be the communication between Google and my server.

Update: I just checked, and although there are still timeout errors Google eventually succeeds at notifying Satchmo after a couple tries. Is it normal for Google to timeout like that? Is there any way to stop it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One place to start is to look at your server logs and see how long it takes to respond to notifications. You need to respond within 3 seconds, otherwise Checkout times out and will try again:

https://checkout.google.com/support/sell/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=59782

Here is some additional info about Integration Console errors:

http://code.google.com/apis/checkout/articles/Troubleshoot_Integration_Console_Errors.html

Generally, by checking your server logs you can see if the timeout is performance related or maybe a special case bug in your server code.

Each notification is sent until your server has acknowledged it successfully, or until 14 days have elapsed. From your description it appears that you are eventually handling notifications correctly.